# Ordered Chi squared or trend tests

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, ordinal-data, contingency-tables, test-for-trend

I've applied the Stata non-parametric test for trend (***nptrend***) for a two-way table including one ordered categorical data (quintiles of deprivation index).

Such clearly ordered variables are straightforward, but what about variables such as education (where there is a general order, but some categories are not clearly higher or lower than others: apprenticeship vs secondary/high school) or smoking/alcohol (current/ex/never, where an order can be argued - exposure - but not clearly: quitting may or may not resolve different aspects of health detriment).

I appreciate that the answer predominantly depends on the reserach question (eg in the case of smoking/alcohol). From the statistical tests' point of view, are there any recommendations about how overtly ordered a variable need to be, before one should use ordered/trend tests instead of ordinary chi squared? And whether there is preference over different trend tests ([eg 1,](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_09.html) [2,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonckheere%27s_trend_test) [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%E2%80%93Armitage_test_for_trend) etc)?